# What is the abutment filtration of the second spectral sequence of hypercohomology?

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I have been recently learning about spectral sequences, following mainly [Illusie's notes](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiouyang/Illusie.pdf) and EGA, and I am about to write some expository notes, but there are still some points that I was not able to justify. One of them is the following: let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be two abelian categories and let $T:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be an additive functor. Assume that $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives and that $\mathbf{D}^+(\mathcal{B})$ exists. Therefore $T$ has a right derived functor $\mathbf{R}T : \mathbf{D}^+(\mathcal{A}) \to \mathbf{D}^+(\mathcal{B})$ and we will denote by $\mathbf{R}^i T$ the composition of $\mathbf{R}T$ and the cohomology functor $H^i : \mathbf{D}^+(\mathcal{B}) \to \mathcal{B}$.

Given $K \in \mathbf{D}^+(\mathcal{A})$, it is possible to construct two biregular spectral sequences abutting to the hypercohomology $\mathbf{R}^*T(K)$. The first one has $E_1$ term $R^qT(K^p)$ and its abutment filtration is given by 
$$ 'F^p(\mathbf{R}^nT(K)) = \text{Im}(\mathbf{R}^nT(\sigma_{\geq p}K) \to \mathbf{R}^nT(K)), $$
where $\sigma_{\geq p}K$ denotes the naive truncation of $K$.

The second one has $E_2$ term $R^pT(H^qK)$ and Illusie claims (p.189 of the above-mentioned notes) that the abutment filtration in this case is given by
$$ ''F^p(\mathbf{R}^nT(K)) = \text{Im}(\mathbf{R}^nT(\tau_{\leq n-p}K) \to \mathbf{R}^nT(K)), $$
where $\tau_{\leq n-p}K$ denotes the canonical truncation of $K$. I have tried to justify this without success. Illusie says that we need to use the method of *décalage* by Deligne. After some search I believe that he is referring to Deligne's *Théorie de Hodge II*, §1. It seems that we need to shift some indices, but I did not follow the argument given there and would appreciate if someone elaborated on this a bit.

Just to make things clear, I am following the standard construction of the spectral sequences of hypercohomology, namely, given $K$ we take an injective Cartan-Eilenberg resolution $L$ for it and consider the spectral sequences of the bicomplex $T(L)$. I would appreciate even more if your answers follow this approach.

Comment: Just like the naive truncation the canonical filtration can be understood as a filtration by subcomplexes. So we eventually end up with something that looks suspiciously like the spectral sequence for cohomology of a filtered complex. One must replace cohomology $H^n$ with ${\bf R}^nT$ in the theory for that spectral sequence.

Comment: @Wilberd van der Kallen: Thanks for your comment! I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, so my apologies if this is indeed the case. To get spectral sequences of hypercohomology we need $T$-acyclic filtered resolutions (Deligne's above-mentioned article (1.4.5)). The easiest way I know to obtain them is to take an injective Cartan-Eilenberg resolution $L$ for $K$ and then consider the quasi-isomorphism from $K$ to the total complex $\text{Tot}(L)$ of $L$. The problem here is to relate the naive (resp. canonical) filtrations of the complex $K$...

Comment: ... with the filtrations of $\text{Tot}(L)$ induced from the filtrations by columns (resp. rows) of the bicomplex $L$. The first one is very easy to justify, since $'\sigma_{\geq p}L$ (this is the notation I use to denote the filtration by columns of $L$) is an injective Cartan-Eilenberg resolution of $\sigma_{\geq p} K$. On the other hand, due to the asymmetry of Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions, I don't see how can we relate the canonical filtration of $K$ with the filtration by rows of $L$. This is where we should use the so called method of *décalage*.

Comment: One should not take the spectral sequence of a bicomplex as the template. This spectral sequence is just one (too particular) case of the spectral sequence of a filtered complex. One should take the spectral sequence of a filtered complex as the template. Look for a more relevant filtration of $\text{Tot}(L)$.

Comment: In some old notes I found the comment that this is much easier to understand when using the derived couples of Massey, rather than Cartan-Eilenberg resolutions. Just apply ${\bf R}T$ to the triangle $\oplus_n \tau_{\leq n-1}K\to \oplus_n \tau_{\leq n}K\to \oplus_n H^n(K)\to$.

Comment: @Wilberd van der Kallen: Thanks for your comments. Concerning the first one, it's true that we can endow $\text{Tot}(L)$ with its canonical filtration (actually $\tau_{\leq -p} \text{Tot}(L)$ in order to get a decreasing one) and then get a $T$-acyclic filtered resolution $K \to \text{Tot}(L)$. This is the approach taken by Deligne, but if I'm not missing something, this won't answer the question regarding the comparison with the spectral sequence obtained from the filtration of $\text{Tot}(L)$ induced by the filtration by rows of the bicomplex.

Comment: Concerning your second comment, I'm not familiar with the derived couples of Massey, so I cannot carry over this argument, sorry.